# IMAP state displays as disconnected - NodeJS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, imap

I am trying to figure out the state of IMAP to Gmail account.

```
var Imap = require('imap');
var imapConnection = new Imap({
username: '',
password: '',
host: "imap.gmail.com",
port: 993,
debug: console.log
});
function testemail(){
imapConnection.connect();
if(imapConnection.state == 'authenticated'){
console.log('yay authenticated')
}
else{
console.log('No success:'+imapConnection.state)
}
}

**Output display:**

No success:disconnected

․[connection] Connected to host
```

I am confused as why it says that it connected to host and  when I print the state of IMAP, it says as "Disconnected" ?

Comment: So `.connect()` starts connecting and returns without waiting. [The first example on github](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap#examples) shows how to run code once the connection is ready to use.

Comment: @arnt - Thanks. I am trying to connect to my inbox of gmail account but how much ever I try, it always refuses the connect and during execution, program ignores thew statement altogether i.e. After I enter the "Imap.connect()", I try to write as "Imap.on('ready',()=>{});. This "ready" is completely ignored. Any help on this.

Comment: `Connected to host` doesn't look as if it always refuses the connection...

Answer (score 1):

node-imap module is quite difficult to handle. There is an easier alternative called [ImapFlow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imapflow). As it uses async functions and promises then you do not have to track callbacks:

```js
const { ImapFlow } = require("imapflow");

const client = new ImapFlow({
  host: "outlook.office365.com",
  port: 993,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: "example.user@hotmail.com",
    pass: "secretpass",
  },
  logger: false, // set to true if you want to see IMAP transaction logs
});

// can't run await in main scope, have to wrap it to an async function
async function main() {
  // establish the connection and log in
  try {
    await client.connect();
    console.log('yay authenticated')
  } catch (err) {
    // connection failed for whatever reason
    console.log('connection failed');
    throw err;
  }

  // open INBOX folder
  let mailbox = await client.mailboxOpen("INBOX");

  // list all unseen messages
  for await (let msg of client.fetch(
    {
      // search query to filter messages
      // https://imapflow.com/global.html#SearchObject
      seen: false
    },
    {
      // attributes to request for
      // https://imapflow.com/global.html#FetchQueryObject
      uid: true,
      flags: true,
      internalDate: true
    }
  )) {
    // extract variables
    let { seq, uid, flags, internalDate } = msg;

    console.log(`#${seq} Attributes:`, { seq, uid, flags, bodyStructure, internalDate });
  }

  // close the connection
  await client.logout();
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

imap.connect() should be written at the last. In nodeJS, you have to specify the event emitter function first and then trigger the event.

source: [https://medium.com/developers-arena/nodejs-event-emitters-for-beginners-and-for-experts-591e3368fdd2#:~:text=At%20the%20time%20of%20publishing%20the%20event%2C%20there%20must%20be%20an%20EventEmitter%20listener%20existing%20to%20listen%20to%20the%20published%20event](https://medium.com/developers-arena/nodejs-event-emitters-for-beginners-and-for-experts-591e3368fdd2#:%7E:text=At%20the%20time%20of%20publishing%20the%20event%2C%20there%20must%20be%20an%20EventEmitter%20listener%20existing%20to%20listen%20to%20the%20published%20event).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).